Is there any way to get more detailed syntax error messages in Redshift SQL?
I am re-writing some 1000+ line queries which were written originally for a PostgreSQL DB and now have to run on near-identical data in Redshift (using Redshift Serverless and the QueryEditorV2). This involves renaming tables to their new data lake names, replacing time conversion functions with native Redshift ones and a few other trivial tasks. It should not be hard, however a major issue I'm running into is just how vague the error messages are. I'll get stuff like this:
AwsClientException: EntityNotFoundException from glue - Entity Not Found [ErrorId: 1-6758cb5d-42b237780f48ac16384ac167]
No pointing to a line, nor mention of what "entity" was not found. I have not found a better way to narrow down the issue than to read the query from top to bottom looking for something that might match this vague description. Is there some log somewhere with more details on what went wrong? Any other tips on figuring out what is syntactically incorrect in a Redshift SQL query?

Have you enabled query logging in Redshift?
Enable detailed logging in Redshift to capture more information about query execution. You can do this by modifying your Redshift parameter group to enable enable_user_activity_logging and log_statement parameters. This will log detailed information about each query execution, which can help identify the problematic part of your query.
